# In CTE query, count records in another table based on first table retrieved ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on CTE based query. I have never used this before. I am using the following query which is getting records from user_detail table.

```
 with cte as ( select  cust_ID, parentid, name, joinside,regdate,package,null lnode, null rnode from  user_detail 
 where cust_ID = @nodeid 
 union all select t.cust_ID, t.parentid,t.name, t.joinside,t.regdate,t.package, 
 ISNULL(cte.lnode, CASE WHEN t.joinside = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) lnode, 
 ISNULL(cte.rnode, CASE WHEN t.joinside = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) rnode from  user_detail 
 t inner join cte on cte.cust_ID = t.parentid )

 select @nodeid nodeid,name,cust_ID,parentid,regdate,package from cte 

 where rnode='0' order by cust_id asc option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Above query is giving me 6 columns (nodeid,name,cust_ID,parentid,regdate,package).
Now what i actually want is, i want 7th column which will count rows based on cust_id from another table installments.

I am doing like below but when i add group by in the query it is giving me error..

```
 declare @nodeid int = '1';
 with cte as ( select  cust_ID, parentid, name, joinside,regdate,package,null lnode, null rnode from  user_detail 
 where cust_ID = @nodeid 
 union all select t.cust_ID, t.parentid,t.name, t.joinside,t.regdate,t.package, 
 ISNULL(cte.lnode, CASE WHEN t.joinside = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) lnode, 
 ISNULL(cte.rnode, CASE WHEN t.joinside = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) rnode from  user_detail 
 t inner join cte on cte.cust_ID = t.parentid )

 select @nodeid nodeid,name,ctttt.cust_ID,parentid,regdate,package,insttt.cust_id from cte as ctttt left join installments as insttt 
 on ctttt.cust_id = insttt.cust_id

 where rnode='0' order by ctttt.cust_id asc option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: You can not get all other 6 column by just grouping it by 'cust_id', either you just select cust_id and count using group by cust_id. or just select 6 column without count. you can not do both in same query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sub query`

```
 (select count(*) from installments as insttt  where  ctttt.cust_id = insttt.cust_id ) cnt
```

**Query:**

```
declare @nodeid int = '1';
 with cte as ( select  cust_ID, parentid, name, joinside,regdate,package,null lnode, null rnode
               from  user_detail 
               where cust_ID = @nodeid 
               union all 
               select t.cust_ID, t.parentid,t.name, t.joinside,t.regdate,t.package, 
               ISNULL(cte.lnode, CASE WHEN t.joinside = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) lnode, 
               ISNULL(cte.rnode, CASE WHEN t.joinside = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) rnode 
               from  user_detail t 
               inner join cte on cte.cust_ID = t.parentid )

 select @nodeid nodeid,name,ctttt.cust_ID,parentid,regdate,package,insttt.cust_id , 
        (select count(*) from installments as insttt  where  ctttt.cust_id = insttt.cust_id ) cnt
 from cte as ctttt 
 where rnode='0'
 order by ctttt.cust_id asc option (maxrecursion 0)
```